# printing all contents of array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I am trying to print out the contents of an array after invoking some methods which alter it, in Java I use:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(alg.id));
```

how do I do this in c#?

Comment: See very closely related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075751/how-does-the-tostring-method-work

Comment: a) Use F# (`printfn "%A\n" [| 1, 2, 3 |]`) or b) use Common Lisp (`(let ((arr #(1 2 3))) (print arr))`). After writing some SO answer in C# after many years of using other languages, I cannot believe that a generic output of structs and arrays is still not part of C#.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You may try this:

```
foreach(var item in yourArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Also you may want to try something like this:

```
yourArray.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
```

**EDIT:** to get output in one line [based on your comment]:

```
 Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", yourArray));
 //output style:  [8, 1, 8, 8, 4, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8]
```

**EDIT(2019):** As it is mentioned in other answers it is better to use `Array.ForEach<T>` method and there is no need to do the `ToList` step.

```
Array.ForEach(yourArray, Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Note that .ToString is not necessary since WriteLine has various overloads including a fallback one that takes an Object.

Comment: I used alg.Id.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine), that worked well thanks you. Is it possible to actually print it like: [8, 1, 8, 8, 4, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8]

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Yes. You are right. but what if the item was a custom class with its own `ToString` mechanism.

Comment: On `ForEach` approach use: `expected.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` You may use a Method Reference instead of a lambda that will create a new useless anonymous method.

Comment: Creating a list with `ToList` just to use the `ForEach` method is a horrible practice IMHO.

Comment: anyway there is no need to copy and paste my answer into yours

Comment: What if the array is very big? Is there an easy way to split the one liner into multiple more readable lines? Thanks

Answer (score 97):

There are many ways to do it, the other answers are good, here's an alternative:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", myArrayOfObjects));
```

Comment: I like this because fits well for me in a write to log:e.g. myArrayObjects is _validExtensions:
Write2Log("Start blabla with the exenstions: " + string.Join("-", _validImgExtensions) + " and so on");

Comment: I like this too as it fits well with logging; And if the array element is one of your objects you can override the `ToString()` and handle the formatting there.
`var a  = new [] { "Admin", "Peon" };_log.LogDebug($"Supplied roles are '{string.Join(", ", a)}'.");`

Answer (score 30):

The easiest one, e.g. if you have a string array declared like this:
string[] myStringArray = new string[];

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", myStringArray));
```

Answer (score 26):

I decided to test the speeds of the different methods posted here:

These are the four methods I used.

```cs
static void Print1(string[] toPrint)
{
    foreach(string s in toPrint)
    {
        Console.Write(s);
    }
}

static void Print2(string[] toPrint)
{
    toPrint.ToList().ForEach(Console.Write);
}

static void Print3(string[] toPrint)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", toPrint));
}

static void Print4(string[] toPrint)
{
    Array.ForEach(toPrint, Console.Write);
}
```

The results are as follows:

```
 Strings per trial: 10000
 Number of Trials: 100
 Total Time Taken to complete: 00:01:20.5004836
 Print1 Average: 484.37ms
 Print2 Average: 246.29ms
 Print3 Average: 70.57ms
 Print4 Average: 233.81ms
```

So Print3 is the fastest, because it only has one call to the `Console.WriteLine` which seems to be the main bottleneck for the speed of printing out an array. Print4 is slightly faster than Print2 and Print1 is the slowest of them all.

I think that Print4 is probably the most versatile of the 4 I tested, even though Print3 is faster.

If I made any errors, feel free to let me know / fix them on your own!

EDIT: I'm adding the generated IL below

```
g__Print10_0://Print1
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  stloc.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0003:  stloc.1     
IL_0004:  br.s        IL_0012
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     
IL_0008:  ldelem.ref  
IL_0009:  call        System.Console.Write
IL_000E:  ldloc.1     
IL_000F:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0010:  add         
IL_0011:  stloc.1     
IL_0012:  ldloc.1     
IL_0013:  ldloc.0     
IL_0014:  ldlen       
IL_0015:  conv.i4     
IL_0016:  blt.s       IL_0006
IL_0018:  ret         

g__Print20_1://Print2
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<String>
IL_0006:  ldnull      
IL_0007:  ldftn       System.Console.Write
IL_000D:  newobj      System.Action<System.String>..ctor
IL_0012:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>.ForEach
IL_0017:  ret         

g__Print30_2://Print3
IL_0000:  ldstr       ""
IL_0005:  ldarg.0     
IL_0006:  call        System.String.Join
IL_000B:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0010:  ret         

g__Print40_3://Print4
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  ldftn       System.Console.Write
IL_0008:  newobj      System.Action<System.String>..ctor
IL_000D:  call        System.Array.ForEach<String>
IL_0012:  ret
```

Answer (score 10):

Another approach with the [`Array.ForEach<T> Method (T[], Action<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [`Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
Array.ForEach(myArray, Console.WriteLine);
```

That takes only one iteration compared to `array.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine)` which takes two iterations and creates internally a second array for the `List` (double iteration runtime and double memory consumtion)

Comment: I like your method the best, it's the second fastest as per my test but it's more versatile than the fastest method( in my opinion ).

Answer (score 7):

Starting from **C# 6.0**, when **$** - string interpolation was introduced, there is one more way:

```
var array = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(", ", array)}");

//output
A, B, C
```

Concatenation could be archived using the `System.Linq`, convert the `string[]` to `char[]` and print as a `string`:

```
var array = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
Console.WriteLine($"{new String(array.SelectMany(_ => _).ToArray())}");

//output
ABC
```

Comment: And without string interpolation: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array));`

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can loop through the array printing each element.  Note that System.Object defines a method ToString().  Any given type that derives from System.Object() can override that.

> Returns a string that represents the current object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx

By default the full type name of the object will be printed, though many built-in types override that default to print a more meaningful result.  You can override ToString() in your own objects to provide meaningful output.

```
foreach (var item in myArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString()); // Assumes a console application
}
```

If you had your own class Foo, you could override ToString() like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "This is a formatted specific for the class Foo.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get cute, you could write an extension method that wrote an `IEnumerable<object>` sequence to the console. This will work with enumerables of any type, because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant on T:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] array  = new []{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
            array.Print();

            Console.WriteLine();

            object[] objArray = new object[] {"One", 2, 3.3, TimeSpan.FromDays(4), '5', 6.6f, 7.7m};
            objArray.Print();
        }
    }

    public static class MyEnumerableExt
    {
        public static void Print(this IEnumerable<object> @this)
        {
            foreach (var obj in @this)
                Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

(I don't think you'd use this other than in test code.)

Comment: Took me a while to fully understand but that is very handy, I am used to Python and putting print statements in to help debug so this is good for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the extension method answer by Matthew Watson, but if you're migrating/visiting coming from Python, you may find such a method useful:

```
class Utils
{
    static void dump<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string glue="\n")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(glue, list.Select(x => x.ToString())));
    }
}
```

-> this will print any collection using the separator provided. It's quite limited (nested collections?).

For a script (i.e. a C# console application which only contains Program.cs, and most things happen in `Program.Main`) - this may be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest way that you could print the String by using array!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace arraypracticeforstring
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr = new string[3] { "Snehal", "Janki", "Thakkar" };

            foreach (string item in arr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array of strings you can use [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var array = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D"};
Console.WriteLine(array.Aggregate((result, next) => $"{result}, {next}")); // A, B, C, D
```

that way you can reverses the order by changing the order of the parameters like so

```
Console.WriteLine(array.Aggregate((result, next) => $"{next}, {result}")); // D, C, B, A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop

```
    int[] random_numbers = {10, 30, 44, 21, 51, 21, 61, 24, 14}
    int array_length = random_numbers.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++){
        if(i == array_length - 1){
              Console.Write($"{random_numbers[i]}\n");
        } else{
              Console.Write($"{random_numbers[i]}, ");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you do not want to use the Array function.

```
public class GArray
{
    int[] mainArray;
    int index;
    int i = 0;

    public GArray()
    {
        index = 0;
        mainArray = new int[4];
    }
    public void add(int addValue)
    {

        if (index == mainArray.Length)
        {
            int newSize = index * 2;
            int[] temp = new int[newSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = mainArray[i];
            }
            mainArray = temp;
        }
        mainArray[index] = addValue;
        index++;

    }
    public void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mainArray[i]);
        }
    }
 }
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GArray myArray = new GArray();
        myArray.add(1);
        myArray.add(2);
        myArray.add(3);
        myArray.add(4);
        myArray.add(5);
        myArray.add(6);
        myArray.print();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```