# Adding values to an array, returns "System.Int32[]"

Tags: c#, arrays, return, addition

I am trying to add values to an array and then return the whole array after 10 increments.

```
public int[] multi(int x)
{
    int[] array = new int[10];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = x;
        x += x;
    }
    return array;
}
```

When i call the method, however, it simply returns `System.Int32[]`, instead of (in this case) 5, 10, 15, 20 etc.

```
int[] result = lab.multi(5);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: This is by design.  The default implementation of `.ToString()` defined in `Object` (from which everything derives in .NET) returns the type - in this case `System.Int32[]` (i.e., an array of `Int32`).   `Console.WriteLine()` calls `ToString()` on the object.  You need to loop through the array to print out the element values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printing all contents of array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265247/printing-all-contents-of-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

Function `Console.WriteLine` calls `ToString()` on the object, so for reference types it simply prints the type name, which in your case is `System.Int32[]`.

If you want to print integer array you can use function [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int[] result = lab.multi(5);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine` doesn't have an overload for `int[]`, so it's using the `object` overload which calls the `ToString()` method. `ToString` on `int[]` prints out `System.Int32[]`.

You need to loop through and print out each item.

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```