# c# create instance and add elements to a collection given a type, which can be: Arrays, Lists, Dictionaries, Queues, Stacks

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist, generic-collections

I have the following code

```
public void example(Type t)
{
    var collector = (ICollection)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    Debug.Log(collector);
}
```

this prints

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.ArrayList
```

but I need to add elements

---

Explaining myself better

I have the type of ICollection, I need to take it to a generic structure that allows me to add or insert elements

```
public void example(Type t){

   var my_collector = new AnyClass((ICollection)Activator.CreateInstance(t));

   collector.Add(new element());
   //or
   collector.insert(new element(),0);
}
```

but, I'm not interested in printing the elements, this I did to show the types of collectors that will come.
I'm only interested in adding or inserting elements in the new ICollector

Anyway, thanks for your answers

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the collection elements and 'log' them one by one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of '[printing all contents of array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16265247/3602352)'

Comment: It's looks like an XY problem. Could you please describe what is your initial goal? And by the way you can't extend an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add elements to an ICollection. You'll need to downcast 'collector' to IList, Queue, or Stack:

```
switch (collector)
{
    case IList list:
        list.Add("something");
        break;
    case Queue queue:
        queue.Enqueue("something");
        break;
    case Stack stack:
        stack.Push("something");
        break;
}
```