# string converted ToCharArray is not returning required value

Tags: c#, arrays, char

This is my whole code :

```
using System;

namespace start
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                string nevim = "";                          // prázdná proměnná pro zbytek
                Console.WriteLine("zadej číslo, které chceš převést do binární soustavy: ");

                ulong vstup = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  // uložíme vstup do proměnné
                while (vstup > 0)                           //pokud je vstup větší než 0
                {
                    ulong pocet = vstup % 2;                  // zjistí zbytek po dělení dvojkou
                    nevim = nevim + pocet;                  //   do proměnné přidá zbytek
                    vstup = vstup / 2;                      //   zadané číslo vydělí 2        


                }
                char[] array = nevim.ToCharArray();        
                Array.Reverse(array);                       //otočí výsledek
                Console.WriteLine(array);
                Console.WriteLine(array + "test");



                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            catch
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("nastala nějaká chyba TYY GEJI");
                Console.WriteLine("stiskni libovolné tlačítko pro pokračování");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

i tried "To.CharArray convert method" to reverse the string, when i try to get the output its ok, for example:

```
input = 123
```

output:

```
1111011
```

but when i try to add something to output like:

```
Console.WriteLine(array + "test");
```

the output is:

```
System.Char[]test
```

and i want this as output:

```
1111011 test
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `new string(array)` will turn your char array into a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printing all contents of array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265247/printing-all-contents-of-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to add `string` to `char[]`. In this case .net is trying to convert both values to the same type by calling `array.ToString()` behind the scene. By default it returns type name. In your case it is `System.Char[]`.
To get expected result you should either create string from your array:

```
Console.WriteLine(new String(array) + "test");
```

or convert "test" to array and concatenate arrays. Check [Merging two arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net) for the sample

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(array) + "test");
```