# Arrays across classes

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this concept of getting an array in my driver to accept an array that I have in my class design.

My problem is that the array needs to have multiple types  and I initially tried to make it a 2 dimensional array, but now I'm even more confused than before. I'm trying to take the load of client side as much as possible with this, but it just hasn't worked for me. I saw another post on Stack Overflow where someone made a new array [][,], but I don't think that works in my situation.

The task that I have to do is come up with a formula that I want to make, provide what is needed to make the formula so the client can call it. And remove and resources when it is called. I also have a function called apply that will simulate the creation for the client but not use any resources.

When I run the code that I have, the Console Write Line returns P1CPSC3200.Formula+TypesForArrays[] and I'm not sure why.
I realize my implementation is probably wrong, but I don't want to screw it up more and get more confused.

This is client side in main

```
namespace P1CPSC3200
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Formula formula1 = new Formula(20, 18);
            int Diamonds = formula1.GetDiamond();
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Diamonds: "+ Diamonds);
            int Sticks = formula1.GetStick();
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Sticks: " + Sticks);
            formula1.MakeDiamondSword();
            formula1.MakeDiamondSword();
            formula1.Apply();
            object[] Formulas = new object[1];
            Formulas = formula1.Formulas;
            Console.WriteLine(Formulas);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is in my class design

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Channels;

namespace P1CPSC3200
{
    class Formula
    {
        public class TypesForArrays
        {
            public int numofOre = 2;
            public int numofStick = 1;
            public string Diam = "Diamonds";
            public string Gold = "Gold Ingots";
            public string Iron = "Iron Ingots";
            public string Stick = "Sticks";
        }
        private int Diamond;
        private int Stick;
        public TypesForArrays[] Formulas = new TypesForArrays[1];
        private static int Proficiency = 1;

        private const int P0 = 0;
        private const int P75 = 75;
        private const int P100 = 100;
        private const int P110 = 110;

        private const int PP5 = 5;
        private const int PP10 = 10;
        private const int PP15 = 15;
        private const int PP20 = 20;
        private const int PP25 = 25;
        private const int PP50 = 50;
        private const int PP65 = 65;
        private const int PP75 = 75;

        private static int Percentage()
        {
            const int p_min = 0;
            const int p_max = 100;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int p_perc = rnd.Next(p_min, p_max);
            if (Proficiency == 1)
            {
                if (p_perc <= PP5)
                {
                    return P110;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP20 + PP5)
                {
                    return P0;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP25 + PP20 + PP5)
                {
                    return P75;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP50 + PP25 + PP20 + PP5)
                {
                    return P100;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else if (Proficiency == 2)
            {
                if (p_perc <= PP10)
                {
                    return P110;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP10 + PP10)
                {
                    return P0;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP15 + PP10 + PP10)
                {
                    return P75;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP65 + PP15 + PP10 + PP10)
                {
                    return P100;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else if (Proficiency == 3)
            {
                if (p_perc <= PP5)
                {
                    return P110;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP5 + PP5)
                {
                    return P0;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP15 + PP5 + PP5)
                {
                    return P75;
                }
                else if (p_perc <= PP75 + PP15 + PP5 + PP5)
                {
                    return P100;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public object getFormula()
        {
            return Formulas[1] ;
        }

        public Formula()
        {
            Diamond = 0;
            Stick = 0;
        }

        public Formula(int Dia, int Sti)
        {
            Diamond = Dia;
            Stick = Sti;
        }

        public int GetDiamond()
        {
            return Diamond;
        }

        public int GetStick()
        {
            return Stick;
        }

        public int MakeDiamondSword()
        {
            const int DiamondSword = 10;
            int chance = Percentage();
            if (Diamond > 1 && Stick > 0)
            {
                Diamond = Diamond - 2;
                Stick = Stick - 1;
                if (chance == P75)
                {
                    Proficiency += 1;
                    return DiamondSword * P75;
                }
                else if (chance == P110)
                {
                    Proficiency += 1;
                    return DiamondSword * P110;
                }
                else if (chance == P100)
                {
                    Proficiency += 1;                 
                    return DiamondSword * P100;
                }
                else if (chance == P0)
                {
                    Proficiency += 1;
                    return DiamondSword * P0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public int Apply()
        {
            const int DiamondSword = 10;
            int chance = Percentage();
            if (Diamond > 1 && Stick > 0)
            {
                if (chance == P75)
                {
                    return DiamondSword * P75;
                }
                else if (chance == P110)
                {
                    return DiamondSword * P110;
                }
                else if (chance == P100)
                {
                    return DiamondSword * P100;
                }
                else if (chance == P0)
                {
                    return DiamondSword * P0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is formula1? I didn't understand  what it is

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Can you use [edit], and start your question describing what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: [printing all contents of array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265247/printing-all-contents-of-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You have two options for this: `1)` Have a base class or interface, along with separate classes for Diamond, Gold, Iron, etc, and then have an array for just the base class. (inheritance) Or `2)` Have a class with a string or enum field telling you the kind of item of this class instance. (composition).

Comment: "I am new to C#" - then DO NOT START WITH SOMETHING COMPLICATED. If you are new to programming (which it looks like) and C#, then slowly work up from simple examples.